# Upgrade Windows 8 to Windows 8 Pro fails

Tags: windows-8

I am a msdn user and am trying to upgrade my laptop OS from Windows 8 to Windows Pro by going to Get more features with Windows 8 and trying to key in Windows 8.1 Pro N VL (x64) - DVD (English) product key obtained from there.

I keep getting the error - This key wont work, check it and try again.

What I have is a brand new laptop Inspiron 15R series.

Comment: whats the error?any error code?describe your problem in brief

Answer (score 0):

You can't use use a Win8.1 Pro **N** key to update a normal Core to Pro. You need a Real Win8.1 Pro key. The N and normal Editions are different SKUs and use different keys.